# BeautifulSoup is not scraping ALL anchor tags in a page with .find_all('a'). Am I overlooking something?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping, python-3.3

Okay, so in a terminal, after importing and making the necessary objects--I typed:

```
for links in soup.find_all('a'):
     print(links.get('href'))
```

which gave me all the links on a wikipedia page (roughly 250). No problems.

However, in a program I am coding, I only receive about 60 links (and this is scraping the same wikipedia page) and the ones I DO get are mostly not worth anything. I double checked that I initialized both exactly the same--the only difference is the names of variables. For reference, here is the function where I setup the BS4 object, and grab the desired page:

```
def get_site(hyperLink):
    userSite = urllib3.PoolManager()
    siteData = userSite.request("GET", hyperLink)
    bsd = BeautifulSoup(siteData.data)
    return bsd
```

Later, I grab the elements and append them to a list I will then manipulate:

```
def find_urls(bsd, urls, currentNetloc):
    for links in bsd.find_all('a'):
        urls.append(links.get('href'))
    return urls
```

Other relevant info:

- I am using Python 3.3
- I am using urllib3, BeautifulSoup 4, and urlparse (from urllib)
- I am working in PyCharm (for the actual program)
- Using Lubuntu, if it matters.

After running a command line instance of python3 and importing "sys" I typed and received:

```
$ sys.executable
'/usr/bin/python3'
$ sys.path
['', '/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/setuptools-1.1.5-py3.3.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/pip-1.4.1-py3.3.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.3.2-py3.3.egg', '/usr/lib/python3.3', '/usr/lib/python3.3/plat-i386-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.3/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

After running these commands in a Pycharm project, I received exactly the same results, with the exception that the directories containing my pycharm projects were included in the list.

Comment: Can you give an example of a Wikipedia page on which you're having these issues?

Comment: Yea. I did a lot of testing with http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyceum_(Classical) for example. What i noticed was in the terminal i got a link for, say, "ancient greek" however in my coded project it skipped over nearly all of the links in the content of this page and mostly did the generic ones.

Comment: To double check: is the interpreter that you're using in the terminal and the intepreter that PyCharm is using the same one?

Comment: The lack of scraped urls is happening when i run the program via py charm. When I say running it via the terminal worked properly I mean an actual Linux terminal. If you question is specifically about which version of python,  then yes I used python 3 in both the command line and in pycharm

Comment: Also sorry about brevity and any grammatical errors, I'm on my phone right now.

Comment: @user3204909 no worries. I was talking specifically about whether it was the same *interpreter* - not *version*... Check that `sys.executable` and `sys.path` are the same... BeautifulSoup can use multiple parsers (some better at parsing than others) which I'm taking a stab are on the "default" install, but not seen by BeautifulSoup when running under PyCharm...

Comment: @JonClements I edited my original post with the results of those commands.

Answer (score 2):

This is not my answer. I got it from [here](http://fryandata.wordpress.com/2014/06/17/24/), which has helped me before.

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import csv

    # Create .csv file with headers
    f=csv.writer(open("nyccMeetings.csv","w"))
    f.writerow(["Name", "Date", "Time", "Location", "Topic"])

    # Use python html parser to avoid truncation
    htmlContent = open("nyccMeetings.html")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlContent,"html.parser")

    # Find each row
    rows = soup.find_all('tr')
    for tr in rows:
        cols = tr.find_all('td') # Find each column
        try:
            names = cols[0].get_text().encode('utf-8')
            date = cols[1].get_text().encode('utf-8')
            time = cols[2].get_text().encode('utf-8')
            location = cols[3].get_text().encode('utf-8')
            topic = cols[4].get_text().encode('utf-8')
       except:
            continue
       # Write to .csv file
       f.writerow([names, date, time, location, topic])
```

I think it would be useful to note some of the troubles I ran into while writing this script:

Specify your parser. It is very important to specify the type of html parser that BeautifulSoup will use to parse through the html tree form. The html file that I read into Python was not formatted correctly so BeautifulSoup truncated the html and I was only able to access about a quarter of the records. By telling BeautifulSoup to explicitly use the built-in Python html parser, I was able to avoid this issue and retrieve all records.

Encode to UTF-8. get_text() had some issues with encoding the text inside the html tags. As such, I was unable to write data to the comma-delimited file. By explicitly telling the program to encode to UTF-8, we avoid this issue altogether.

Comment: Please answer the question here. The link may become invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered many problems in my web scraping projects; however, BeautifulSoup was never the culprit.

I highly suspect you are having the same problem I had scraping Wikipedia. Wikipedia did not like my user-agent and was returning a page other than what I requested. Try adding a user-agent in your code e.g. 
`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.146 Safari/537.36`

You mentioned you were using urllib3 so [here](http://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/1.2.1/pools.html) is where you can read on how to use a custom user-agent.

Also if you want to diagnose your problem try this: In the terminal where you said everything was working fine, add an extra line `print len(html)` Then do the same in your program to see if you are in fact getting the links from the same page.